# privilegios em javascript

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Estou tentado fazer uma validação para o usuário: medico não ter acesso ao valor da consulta e os outros usuários ter acesso ao valor da consulta, eu conseguir fazer para não aparecer para o medico,so que ta pegando todos usuários do sistema.

[image: valor da consulta]

[image: sem o valor]

```
function MostraHistoricoPaciente(data, modal, datatype) {

  if(modal) {
    $('#modal-historico').modal();
  }

  if(datatype == 'json') {
    $('#datas-historico').html('');
    $('#content-historico').html('');
    $('.panel-body').html('');
    $('#content-dados').html(
      '<br><div class="row">' +
        '<div class="col-md-3"><strong>Nome:</strong> ' + data[0].dados_paciente[0].nome + '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2"><strong>Profissão:</strong> ' + data[0].dados_paciente[0].profissao + '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2"><strong>Data Nasc:</strong> ' + data[0].dados_paciente[0].data_nasc + '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2"><strong>Idade:</strong> ' + data[0].dados_paciente[0].idade + '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2"><strong>Sexo:</strong> ' + data[0].dados_paciente[0].sexo + '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2"><strong>Estado Civil:</strong> ' + data[0].dados_paciente[0].estado_civil + '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="row"><br>' +
        '<div class="col-md-12"><div class="label label-default">Contato</div><hr></div><br><br>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2"><strong>Tel:</strong> ' + data[0].dados_paciente[0].tel + '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2"><strong>Cel:</strong> ' + data[0].dados_paciente[0].cel + '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-3"><strong>E-mail:</strong> ' + data[0].dados_paciente[0].email + '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="row"><br>' +
        '<div class="col-md-12"><div class="label label-default">Endereço</div><hr></div><br><br>' +
        '<div class="col-md-3"><strong>Rua:</strong> ' + data[0].dados_paciente[0].logradouro + ' ' + data[0].dados_paciente[0].numero + '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-3"><strong>Bairro:</strong> ' + data[0].dados_paciente[0].bairro + '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-3"><strong>Cidade:</strong> ' + data[0].dados_paciente[0].cidade + '/' + data[0].dados_paciente[0].uf + '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-3"><strong>CEP:</strong> ' + data[0].dados_paciente[0].cep + '</div>' +
      '</div>'
      );

        // Aqui
       function renderValueTotal() {
          if($users.privilegy === 3 || $users.privilegy === 4 ) {
          return '<div class="col-md-3"><strong>Valor:</strong> ' +
          lcssafira.app.formatReal(data[0].caixa[0].valor_total, true);
          }
            return '';


          var valueTotal = renderValueTotal($privilegy);


          if(typeof data[0].caixa !== 'undefined') {
          $('#content-dados').append(

          '<div class="row"><br>' +
          '<div class="col-md-12"><div class="label label-default">Pagamento</div><hr></div><br><br>' +
          '<div class="col-md-3"><strong>Forma Pagamento:</strong> ' + data[0].caixa[0].forma_pgto + '</div>' +
          renderValueTotal + 
          '<div>'
          );
        }
      }


    if(typeof data[0].exame !== 'undefined') {
      $('.panel-body').html(data[0].exame[0].modelo);
    }

    $.each(data, function(index, val) {

      icon = '<span class="material-icons">event_available</span>';
      if(typeof val.data_cadastro !== 'undefined') {
        $('#datas-historico').append('<span class="btn btn-raised btn-sm btn-data-diagnostico" data-id-paciente="' 
        + val.id_pessoa +  '" data-date="' + val.data_cadastro + '">' 
        + icon + '<span class="data-cadastro">' 
        + val.data_cadastro + '</span></span>');
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    $('#content-historico').html(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Só com esse código que você postou daria pra reproduzir o problema? Você conseguirá melhores respostas se der às pessoas código que elas possam usar para reproduzir o problema

Comment: normalmente, e digo 'normalmente' porque tem gente que prefere se arriscar e reinventar rodas... todo tratamento de validação, exibição, permissão, deve ser feito no server side, pelo backend, é nele que as validações, sessions, permissões sao manipuladas, JS como client-side, mesmo que não apareça na tela se voce precisa tratar ou ocultar o valor, ele estará no código visível para um usuário pouco mais experiênte.

Comment: sim eu concordo com vc sobre a validação,esse código ja estava assim quando peguei ele e agora vai ficar um pouco complicado de arrumar isso,vou ter que arrumar uma solução a curto prazo e depois a longo prazo eu ir melhorando esse código.